# Как сделать сохранение изменений, сделанных пользователем?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Метод

```
public void CreateLabel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var location = e.Location;
            //
            if (ElementText().Length > 0)
            {
                Label createdlabel = new Label();
                createdlabel.BackColor = buttonBackColor.BackColor;
                createdlabel.ForeColor = buttonFontColor.BackColor;
                createdlabel.Font = new Font(font, fontsize, fontstyle, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
                createdlabel.Location = new Point((Size)location);
                createdlabel.Name = "createdlabel";
                createdlabel.AutoSize = true;
                createdlabel.Text = $"{ElementText()}";
                createdlabel.BringToFront();
                pictureBoxMain.Controls.Add(createdlabel);
            }
        }
```

подключён к кнопке и по необходимости создаёт на пикчербоксе лэйблы, тем самым пользователь приложения может создавать динамичные надписи на картинке.
Вопрос в том, как можно сохранить то, что пользователь делает в течении сеанса работы с приложением (то есть массив значений всех созданных лейблов с их характеристиками)?
Как реализовать функцию работы с несколькими сохранениями по их названию?

Comment: сделайте класс `LabelData` и в методе сохранения скопируйте нужные свойства из коллекции `Label` в перечисление `LabelData`: `pictureBoxMain.Controls.OfType<Label>().Select(label => new LabelData() { ... })`. Затем [сериализируйте это в JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) и сохраните. Обратно всё тоже самое, только наоборот